# How do I adress an item/index in an array in Azure Data Factory - Data Flow - Flatten

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I have a JSON source that looks like this:

```
{
   "columnNames":[
      "Screw",
      "Type",
      "Class_Region",
      "Orders/Sales",
      "Quarter-3",
      "Previous Quarter %",
      "Previous Year %",
      "Quarter-2",
      "Previous Quarter %",
      "Previous Year %",
      "Quarter-1",
      "Previous Quarter %",
      "Previous Year %",
      "Quarter",
      "Previous Quarter %",
      "Previous Year %",
      "Total",
      "Previous Year %"
   ],
   "analysisData":[
      [
         "Single Screw",
         "Fields of Application (1.000€)",
         "Blown film",
         "Orders",
         "146.700",
         "119,4",
         "39,7",
         "147.088",
         "0,3",
         "17,0",
         "166.429",
         "13,1",
         "54,6",
         "119.562",
         "-28,2",
         "78,9",
         "579.779",
         "43,1"
      ],
      [
         "Single Screw",
         "Fields of Application (1.000€)",
         "Blown film",
         "Sales",
         "84.290",
         "-16,9",
         "-10,7",
         "122.121",
         "44,9",
         "-17,4",
         "102.930",
         "-15,7",
         "15,1",
         "128.227",
         "24,6",
         "26,4",
         "437.568",
         "1,0"
      ],
      [
         "Single Screw",
         "Fields of Application (1.000€)",
         "Flat film",
         "Orders",
         "56.077",
         "9,1",
         "13,8",
         "85.338",
         "52,2",
         "125,7",
         "41.544",
         "-51,3",
         "-8,5",
         "102.514",
         "146,8",
         "99,4",
         "285.473",
         "55,2"
      ]
   ],
   "resCode":0,
   "message":"OK!"
}
```

I want to load it into a Azure SQL Table via Data Flow. I tried "Flatten" and I think it is the right step but how to map the columns? What is the correct syntax?

What I need is something like this:

```
analysisData[0] -> Screw
analysisData[1] -> Type
analysisData[2] -> Class_Region
```

What is the syntax for the index in the array (something like analysisData[0])?

Comment: After you flatten the column names into row values, you can try Pivot to turn those into the column names

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `analysisData[]` to call values screw, Type, class-region.
Please use `columnNames[]` to get same or please you the Mark's mentioned comment where you have to Flatten the column names into row values and again you have to turn those using Pivot to map the columns.